# How to properly prefetch_related in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

One query is more than 10 times faster than the other, it looks like prefetch_related has no effect. How to do it correctly?

```
# 400ms
test = PZItem.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('quantity'))

# 4000ms
test = PZ.objects.prefetch_related('pzitem_set').aggregate(Sum('pzitem__quantity'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`.aggregate` is already a database function. There is no need to prefetch all related items first.

You need `prefetch_related` for example if you iterate over items:

```py
from django.models.db import Prefetch

test = PZ.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'pzitem_set',
        queryset=PZItem.objects.filter(active=True),  # optional qs filter
        to_attr='pzitem_list'
    )
)

# version 1 with prefetch
for pz in test:
    for item in pz.pzitem_list:
        # this does NOT hit the db everytime as the pzitem_list is prefetched
        print(item)

# version 2 without prefetch
for pz in test:
    for item int ps.pzitem_set.all():
        # this will hit the database for every pz in the parent loop
        print(item)
```